# sending a user defined value from active directory

Tags: active-directory

Is it possible to set a custom value for the service that active directory is providing?

I am having hard time figuring this out as all the research I did on microsoft, oracle, and MIT websites yielded nothing.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your Kerberos is tied to an Active Directory.

Consider adding a custom attribute in Active Directory instead, for example, 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20319.how-to-create-a-custom-attribute-in-active-directory.aspx

You could get principal name from a Kerberos ticket, then make request to AD to get that custom attribute for that principal. (assuming your custom attributes could be at a principal level)

I don't think you could create custom attributes for the ticket itself.